# C++ virtual template member function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

```
#include <iostream>

class Data_X {
public:
  Data_X(int x): x(x) {}
  int getData() {
    return x;
  }
private:
  int x;
};

class parent {
public:
  template <typename T>
   T* getDataPtr() { //**can't make virtual here**
    std::cout << "No get DataPtr not implemented" << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
  }
};

class child1 : public parent {
public:
  child1(int x) {
    datax = new Data_X(x);
  }
  template <typename T>
  T* getDataPtr() {
    return datax;
  }
private:
  Data_X *datax;
};

int main() {

  std::unique_ptr<parent> p1 = std::make_unique<child1>(1);
  Data_X* dataPtr = p1->getDataPtr<Data_X>();

  dataPtr->getData();
  return 0;
}
```

Data_X* dataPtr = p1->getDataPtr<Data_X>(); calls the parent getDataPtr() function, what changes are require to call getDataPtr() child1 member function with parent(p1) object.

Expectation is to call child1 templated getDataPtr() member function with parent(p1) object.

Comment: In general don't mix static and dynamic polymorphism, virtual functions should be generic (can't be specialized on datatypes). So you shouldn't ask for data using virtual functions you should ask the class to work on its member data (which can be templated in the derived class).

Comment: you didnt actually ask a question. Note that "why can I not make the virtual method a template?" and "What to do instead?" are related but slightly different. I picked a duplciate that covers the former. For the latter you need to explain more what the aim is (but I suppose there are duplicates too)

Comment: Why does it need to be a template? What should happen if `p1->getDataPtr<Something_From_Outer_Space>()` is called?

Answer (score 0):

What my comment looks like in code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class some_interface
{
public:
    virtual ~some_interface() = default;
    virtual void do_something_with_data() = 0;
};

template<typename type_t>
class some_class_t final :
    public some_interface
{
public: 
    explicit some_class_t(const type_t& data) :
        m_data{data}
    {
    }

    void do_something_with_data() override
    {
        std::cout << m_data << "\n";
    }

private:
    type_t m_data;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<some_interface> int_object = std::make_unique<some_class_t<int>>(42);
    std::unique_ptr<some_interface> string_object = std::make_unique<some_class_t<std::string>>("Hello");

    int_object->do_something_with_data();
    string_object->do_something_with_data();

    return 1;
}
```